# my POST request changes to GET and execution stops

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-services

i have a problem with the `.map` function. It seems to change my explicit POST request to a GET. Its showed in the url bar and also GET shows up in Fiddler.
 My first question is: Why is that and how do I fix that?

My second question is, how do I extract this very simple JSON reponse
`JSON="asfdsflkdsfnlkds.dsfdsergrnkger.ynttyjokhn"`
 from the server properly and pass it to the `JwtToken` variable?

Here is my service that does the POST:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { /*HTTP_PROVIDERS, */ Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { AuthHttp } from 'angular2-jwt';
//import { map } from 'rxjs';


class JwtToken {
    token: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {

    jwtToken: any;

    constructor(public authHttp: AuthHttp) { }

    //jwtHeader = new Headers({
    //    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    //    "alg": "HS256",
    //    "typ": "JWT"
    //});

    Login(username: string, password: string) {
        this.authHttp.post('/api/login',
            {
                "username": username,
                "password": password
            }
            //,{ headers: this.jwtHeader }
        ).map(res => <JwtToken>res.json())
            .subscribe(
            data => {
                console.log(data);
                this.jwtToken = data;
            }
            );

        console.log(this.jwtToken);

        return this.jwtToken;
    }

}
```

btw. I couldn't import the `map` from `rxjs`. It gives me an error. There, however, seems to be `.map` anyway.

Comment: import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

Comment: Oh raw `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; ` actually worked! That answers my first question. Thanks! And how do I extract the token from the data?

Comment: @StanislawT, Why do you thing that `map` changes POST request to a GET?

Comment: Nevermind! All seems to be working now! If you post your import suggestion as an answer, Im gonna mark it down as the right one.

Comment: @StanislawT, What is the problem with token extraction? Code looks valid.

Comment: I just got confused and forgot about asynchronous execution! The `console.log(this.jwtToken);` was giving me `undefined` on first run which is actually correct! Silly me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import as:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```